# Replace a char in the string with HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing, element

I'm getting system logs from the server and feeding them to my widget which appends new logs to the log-container element. Logs look like this:

```
2017-06-0512:11:53.066|error[61f4cdd07abb]sequential(sequential)|interval(0)Error:...
```

I'm appending with jquery like this:

```
 returnElement.append('<span class="message">' + log.message + '  </span><br>');
```

However, I would like to style these pipe symbols which act like delimiters in the logs **|**

Whats the best way to do this? Will probably have to wrap them with another span but I would like to avoid substringing each log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a RegExp, e.g.: `msg.replace(/(\|)/g, '<span class="delimiter">$1</span>')`

```js
var msg = '2017-06-0512:11:53.066|error[61f4cdd07abb]sequential(sequential)|interval(0)Error:...';

document.write('<span>' + msg.replace(/(\|)/g, '<span class="delimiter">$1</span>') + '</span>');
```

```css
.delimiter {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin: 10px;
}
```